# How to add a bitmap Image as Combo Box Item in WPF programmatically?

Tags: wpf, combobox

How do I add a bitmap Image as Combo Box Item in WPF programmatically ?

I am creating `ComboBox` dynamically as:

```
private ComboBox CreateSymbolComboBox(List<BitmapImage> images, int selectedIndex, bool isEnabled)
    {
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

        foreach (BitmapImage img in images)
        {

            cb.Items.Add();
        }

        return cb;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitmapImage` actually derives from `ImageSource`. So you can use it as the `Source` of `Image`. Observe:

```
private ComboBox CreateSymbolComboBox(List<BitmapImage> images, int selectedIndex, bool isEnabled)
{
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

    foreach (BitmapImage img in images)
    {

        cb.Items.Add(new Image() {Source = img});
    }

    return cb;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's always helpful to see which superclass a class derives from.